# XSS in a variable assignment when <>" are escaped

Tags: xss, javascript, waf

**SCENARIO:**

user input is reflected inside a variable.
For example

```
url.com/?a=hello
```

is reflected as shown below

```
var test="hello";
```

I tried to evade from the variable with payload like `hello";`  or `hello%22;` or `hello%2522;` but unsuccessfully.
All these characters are reflected without encoding: `.[]{};:{}\/?|_-+` so i can use them

Is there another way to exploit this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not given the filter behavior you specified.

- You need double quotes (`"`) to exit the JS string context.
- You need angle brackets (`<>`) to exit the `<script>` tag which I presume surrounds the code.
- You can use a backslash (`\`) at the end of the string to escape the closing quote, however you'd need another injection point on the *same line* to do anything useful with that. Otherwise you're unable to close the string you've now kept open, and the JS parser will throw a syntax error, implying it does not execute any part of the script.

  Here is how an attack would work with two injection points.

  Code:

  ```
  var test="hello"; var test2="stranger";
  ```

  Vectors:

  ```
            \                  ;alert()//
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  var test="\"; var test2=";alert()//";
           |--------------|        |--|
         one continuous string    comment
  ```